# Restore Visual Studio 2013 ToolBox

Tags: visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit

2 Issues with VS 2013:

- I have the default toolbox and also the AjaxToolkit toolbox, everything is working properly until I uninstall the AjaxToolkit and the toolbox is gone, I reset window layout, reset the toolbox but it is still empty.
  **How to get the default toolbox back?**
- Secondly, I accidentally open the PerformanceExplorer in one of the project and can't not make it disappear, every time I open that project the PerformanceExplorer will pop up, that very annoying. anyuone know **how to close the PerformanceExplorer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer for 1st issue from: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18560

> The following steps allow you to reset the Toolbox completely and
>   enable Visual Studio to rebuilt it from scratch. In most cases, this
>   procedure solves all issues related to Silverlight toolbox items.
>
> Above all, reset the Toolbox from Visual Studio. For this right-click
>   the Toolbox and click the "Reset Toolbox" item. After the reset
>   procedure is done, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Close Visual Studio;
> 2. Open the "c:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0"
>      (Windows 7) folder and remove all the .TBD files; (**10.0** is VS 2010, **12** is VS 2013 etc.)
> 3. Run the "regedit" tool. For this click the "Run" item in the Start menu and type "regedit" without quotation marks;
> 4. Find the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ToolboxControlsInstaller_AssemblyFoldersExCache"
>      and
>      "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ToolboxControlsInstallerCache"
>      keys;
> 5. Remove everything from these keys leaving them empty; (delete all folders under **ToolboxControlsInstaller_AssemblyFoldersExCache** and
>      **ToolboxControlsInstallerCache**)
> 6. Run Visual Studio again and open a project and wait until it recreates all items in the Toolbox.

For second issue looks like it is a bug that has not been fixed yet